# Deciding on implementation of ExceptionFilterAttribute OnException method

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am trying to implement exception handling for Web Api using ExceptionFilterAttribute. I have inherited ExceptionFilterAttribute class and overridden the onException method.

```
public class ApiLogExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext != null)
        {
            Logger.LogException(actionExecutedContext.Exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Lately, I have seen some implementation where the base class OnException method is also called in the overridden implementation.

```
public class ApiLogExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext != null)
            {
                base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
                Logger.LogException(actionExecutedContext.Exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

Which of the above two implementation is advisable? what is the use calling base method in this scenario?

Comment: If you read the MSDN docs then this would be wise: "Raises the exception event".  But ExceptionFilterAttribute does not have an event and OnException() does not doing anything at all since it is an empty method.  Hmm.  Hard to give good advice when the docs are so shoddy, but I'd personally try to avoid doing things that don't make no sense.

Comment: Exactly, the doc does not make it clear what the virtual method does. That is why I was confused with how to implement, since I saw base call implementation and was wondering is it something I don't know. Its better, I will avoid base method call. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question, so based on https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Filters/ExceptionFilterAttribute.cs (I hope it is current source of code) there is no point in calling `base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);`

Also from the nature of the filters, you can register multiple filters and you do not need inheritance for chaining. 
In theory you can call base just in case the current implementation changes and there is really anything done in the abstract base class.
I am not calling it in my implementation.